typescript issue with express,multer at req.file.key and re.file.location
Impossible to find a solution about how to typescript key and location
First is use a middleware who communicate with amazon S3 for my picture on my website.
typescript error:
Property 'key' does not exist on type 'File'.
Property 'location' does not exist on type 'File'.

The issue is in my file product.ts
/*modules*/
import express from 'express';
/*models*/
import Raffle, { IRaffle } from '../../models/Raffle';
import RafflePlayer from '../../models/RafflePlayer';
import MystBox, { IMystBox } from '../../models/MystBox';
import MystBoxPlayer from '../../models/MystBoxPlayer';
import BreakCode from '../../models/BreakCode';
import WlOrMint from '../../models/WlOrMint';
import SimpleCard from '../../models/SimpleCard';
/*middleware*/
import fetchNFTData from '../../middleware/fetchNftData';
import connectAwsS3 from '../../middleware/connect-awsS3';
/*fetch*/
import getMetadatNft from '../../services/metadataNft';
import BreakEncrypt from '../../models/BreakEncrypt';
import BreakGuess from '../../models/BreakGuess';
import BreakPlayer from '../../models/BreakPlayer';


router.post(
    '/addmyst',
    connectAwsS3.uploadCardImage.single('imagemystbox'),
    async (req, res) => {
        if (!req.file) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error:
                    'No image provided or your image has not the extenions jpeg|jpg|png. Try again!',
            });
        }
        try {
            const {
                title,
                nbrmystbox,
                exp,
                price,
                posted,
                startdate,
                enddate,
                currentdate,
            } = req.body;

            console.log('reqbody', req.body);

            console.log(
                'var',
                title,
                nbrmystbox,
                exp,
                price,
                startdate,
                enddate,
                currentdate
            );

            let error = '';
            const prizes = JSON.parse(req.body.prizes);
            console.log('prizes', prizes, typeof prizes);

            if (!title.trim()) {
                error = 'Title is empty.';
            } else if (!nbrmystbox) {
                error = 'Nbr mystBox is empty.';
            } else if (!price) {
                error = 'Price is empty.';
            } else if (!exp) {
                error = 'Exp is empty.';
            } else if (!startdate) {
                error = 'Start date is empty.';
            } else if (!enddate) {
                error = 'End date is empty.';
            } else if (prizes.length === 0) {
                error = 'No prize added.';
            }

            if (error) {
                // Suppression de l'image de S3 en cas d'erreur
                if (req.file && req.file.key) {
                    const cleanedKey = req.file.key.replace('MystBox/', ''); // Supprime le préfixe

                    console.log('deletefile1', req.file, req.file.key);
                    await connectAwsS3.deleteImageFromS3(cleanedKey, 'MystBox');
                }

                return res.status(400).json({ error });
            }

            const imageUrl = req.file.location;
            console.log('imageUrl :>> ', imageUrl);

            const mystBoxData: IMystBox = new MystBox({
                title,
                nbrmystbox,
                prize: prizes,
                exp,
                price,
                posted,
                image: imageUrl,
            });

            console.log('mystboxdata1', mystBoxData);
            if (posted === 'on') {
                const currentDate = new Date(currentdate);
                const startDate = new Date(startdate);
                const endDate = new Date(enddate);

                if (currentDate < startDate) {
                    mystBoxData.status = 'Upcoming';
                } else if (currentDate >= startDate && currentDate <= endDate) {
                    mystBoxData.status = 'Ongoing';
                } else {
                    mystBoxData.status = 'Ended';
                }

                mystBoxData.startdate = startDate;
                mystBoxData.enddate = endDate;
            }
            console.log('mystboxdata2', mystBoxData);

            await mystBoxData.save();

            return res.status(201).json({ message: 'Mysterybox added successfully.' });
        } catch (err: any) {
            let errorMessage = 'Impossible to create the mysterybox!';

            // Gestion des erreurs
            if (err.code === 11000) {
                errorMessage = 'That title already exists!';
            }

            // Suppression de l'image de S3 si elle a été téléchargée
            if (req.file && req.file.key) {
                const cleanedKey = req.file.key.replace('MystBox/', ''); // Supprime le préfixe

                console.log('deletefile2', req.file, req.file.key);
                await connectAwsS3.deleteImageFromS3(cleanedKey, 'MystBox');
            }

            return res.status(400).json({ error: errorMessage });
        }
    }
);

My s3 middleware connect-awsS3.ts
/* eslint-disable no-console -- console*/

import path from 'node:path';
import multer from 'multer';
import multerS3 from 'multer-s3';
import { S3Client, DeleteObjectCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express'; // Ajout des types

const s3Client = new S3Client({
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION as string,
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY_S3 as string,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_KEY_S3 as string,
    },
});
const bucketName = process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME!;

// Middleware pour l'upload
const upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3Client,
        bucket: bucketName,
        async key(req, file, cb) {
            let folder = ''; // Initialisation du dossier

            if (file && file.fieldname === 'imagemystbox') {
                folder = 'MystBox/';
            } else if (file && file.fieldname === 'imagebreakcode') {
                folder = 'BreakCode/';
            } else if (file && file.fieldname === 'questFiles') {
                folder = 'Quest/';
            } else if (file && file.fieldname === 'imagewlormint') {
                folder = 'WlOrMint/';
            } else if (file && file.fieldname === 'airdropFiles') {
                folder = 'Airdrop/';
            }

            // Ajouter d'autres conditions pour d'autres types si nécessaire
            console.log('Generated folder:', folder); // Vérifie le dossier généré

            const fileExtension = path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase();
            const newFilename = uuidv4() + fileExtension; // Génère un nouvel identifiant unique pour le nom du fichier

            cb(null, folder + newFilename); // Utilisez le nouveau nom de fichier
        },
        acl: 'public-read',
        metadata(req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname });
        },
    }),
    limits: { fileSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024 }, // Max file size is 10MB
    fileFilter(req: Request, file, cb) {
        const fileTypes = /jpeg|jpg|png/;
        const extname = fileTypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
        const mimetype = fileTypes.test(file.mimetype);
        console.log('Nom du fichier :', file.originalname); // Ajout du console.log ici

        if (extname && mimetype) {
            return cb(null, true);
        }
        // Signaler une erreur de type de fichier à la route
        req.invalidFileType = true;
        cb(null, false);
    },
});

// Fonction pour supprimer l'image de S3
const deleteImageFromS3 = async (key: string, type: string) => {
    const folder = `${type}/`; // Dossier basé sur le type

    const params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: folder + key,
    };

    try {
        await s3Client.send(new DeleteObjectCommand(params));
        console.log(`Successfully deleted ${key} from S3`);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Error deleting ${key} from S3:`, err);
    }
};

export default {
    uploadCardImage: upload,
    deleteImageFromS3,
};



I have create a folder types at the root of my backend and put it in include of my tsconfig.json
declare module 'connect-awsS3' {
    import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

    interface File {
        key: string;
        location: string;
    }

    type Upload = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => void;

    type DeleteImageFromS3 = (key: string, type: string) => Promise<void>;

    const uploadCardImage: Upload;
    const deleteImageFromS3: DeleteImageFromS3;

    export { uploadCardImage, deleteImageFromS3 };
}


And this is my tsconfig.json file:
{
    "extends": "@repo/typescript-config/base.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["ES2015"],
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "esModuleInterop": true
        // Autres options de configuration spécifiques à votre projet...
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"],
    "include": [
        "src",
        "types" // Assurez-vous que "types" est bien inclus s'il s'agit du répertoire où se trouve connect-awsS3.d.ts
    ]
}


Now it is 4 hour i am on it i have looked on the web and dontfind a solution and no too with some Ai model.
If some good dev can help me find the solution i thanks you by advance.
I have try to create d.ts file for req.file.key and req.file location but apparently it is not correct the issue.

In my root folder types i have change the file connect-awS3.d.ts like that
// types/connect-awsS3.d.ts

import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

interface ExtendedFile extends Express.Multer.File {
    key: string;
    location: string;
}

type Upload = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => void;
type DeleteImageFromS3 = (key: string, type: string) => Promise<void>;

declare function uploadCardImage(
    req: Request,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction
): void;
declare function deleteImageFromS3(key: string, type: string): Promise<void>;

export { ExtendedFile, uploadCardImage, deleteImageFromS3 };

And afteri have import that file directly wher i have my road in product.ts
/* eslint-disable no-console -- console */

/*modules*/
import express from 'express';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
/*models*/
import MystBox, { IMystBox } from '../../models/MystBox';
import MystBoxPlayer, { IMystBoxPlayer } from '../../models/MystBoxPlayer';

import connectAwsS3 from '../../middleware/connect-awsS3';
import { ExtendedFile } from '../../../types/connect-awsS3';






router.post(
    '/addmyst',
    connectAwsS3.uploadCardImage.single('imagemystbox'),
    async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        if (!req.file || !('key' in req.file) || !('location' in req.file)) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error:
                    'No image provided or your image has not the extenions jpeg|jpg|png. Try again!',
            });
        }

        // Maintenant, TypeScript reconnaîtra les propriétés 'key' et 'location'
        const { key, location } = req.file as ExtendedFile;
        console.log('Clé du fichier :', key);
        console.log('Emplacement du fichier :', location);

        try {
            const {
                title,
                nbrmystbox,
                exp,
                price,
                posted,
                startdate,
                enddate,
                currentdate,
            } = req.body;

            console.log('reqbody', req.body);

            console.log(
                'var',
                title,
                nbrmystbox,
                exp,
                price,
                startdate,
                enddate,
                currentdate
            );

            let error = '';
            const prizes = JSON.parse(req.body.prizes);
            console.log('prizes', prizes, typeof prizes);

            if (!title.trim()) {
                error = 'Title is empty.';
            } else if (!nbrmystbox) {
                error = 'Nbr mystBox is empty.';
            } else if (!price) {
                error = 'Price is empty.';
            } else if (!exp) {
                error = 'Exp is empty.';
            } else if (!startdate) {
                error = 'Start date is empty.';
            } else if (!enddate) {
                error = 'End date is empty.';
            } else if (prizes.length === 0) {
                error = 'No prize added.';
            }

            if (error) {
                // Suppression de l'image de S3 en cas d'erreur
                if (req.file && req.file.key) {
                    const cleanedKey =
                        typeof key === 'string' ? key.replace('MystBox/', '') : key;
                    // Supprime le préfixe

                    console.log('deletefile1', req.file, req.file.key);
                    await connectAwsS3.deleteImageFromS3(cleanedKey, 'MystBox');
                }

                return res.status(400).json({ error });
            }

            const imageUrl = req.file.location;
            console.log('imageUrl :>> ', imageUrl);

            const mystBoxData: IMystBox = new MystBox({
                title,
                nbrmystbox,
                prize: prizes,
                exp,
                price,
                posted,
                image: imageUrl,
            });

            console.log('mystboxdata1', mystBoxData);
            if (posted === 'on') {
                const currentDate = new Date(currentdate);
                const startDate = new Date(startdate);
                const endDate = new Date(enddate);

                if (currentDate < startDate) {
                    mystBoxData.status = 'Upcoming';
                } else if (currentDate >= startDate && currentDate <= endDate) {
                    mystBoxData.status = 'Ongoing';
                } else {
                    mystBoxData.status = 'Ended';
                }

                mystBoxData.startdate = startDate;
                mystBoxData.enddate = endDate;
            }
            console.log('mystboxdata2', mystBoxData);

            await mystBoxData.save();

            return res.status(201).json({ message: 'Mysterybox added successfully.' });
        } catch (err: any) {
            let errorMessage = 'Impossible to create the mysterybox!';

            // Gestion des erreurs
            if (err.code === 11000) {
                errorMessage = 'That title already exists!';
            }

            // Suppression de l'image de S3 si elle a été téléchargée
            if (req.file && req.file.key) {
                const cleanedKey =
                    typeof key === 'string' ? key.replace('MystBox/', '') : key;
                console.log('Cleaned key:', cleanedKey);
                // Supprime le préfixe

                console.log('deletefile2', req.file, req.file.key);
                await connectAwsS3.deleteImageFromS3(cleanedKey, 'MystBox');
            }

            return res.status(400).json({ error: errorMessage });
        }
    }
);

```

Lot of people have that issue but they deactivate typescript in them page for spare that error like that you can use typescript.

Have a nice day

